# Alinco DJ 500 is having a problem hitting 440 repeaters, the PL and the offset are good and the input IS IN THE BAND. Other HT works great with rpt

Tags: equipment-troubleshooting, alinco

My Alinco dj 500 worked great for years and suddenly I can’t hit any of the local 440 repeaters with it.  My other ht (tytera md380) works great with these repeaters.  I have the right pl and the input and output frequencies are within the right limits, the offset is 5 MHz and the rig is set to high power.  I finally tried doing a factory reset.  The weirdest thing is that it works great on 2 meters.  My other ht doesn’t have problems picking up 440 transmissions on simplex but the repeaters aren’t picking it up and retransmitting it for some strange reason.

And yes, I reviewed the owner’s manual and the other posts related to the ht not transmitting properly.

Comment: You sure the transmitters didn't at some point start to expect something like CTCSS tones that your hytera transmits, but your alinco doesn't?

Comment: Are you pretty sure this is a configuration issue, or is it possible that the hardware has been damaged? Are you having trouble both transmitting AND receiving on UHF, or only with transmitting e.g. blown final?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the antennas between the two radios?  Or using a 70cm specific antenna instead of the stock antenna?

Answer (score 2):

**First:** Great job on troubleshooting and isolating the problem. Seriously, many folks have a hard time getting this done on their own... kudos!

Since its working well on one band and not the other AND you've got another HT that's working well on both bands:

- You've definitely narrowed it down to a local problem with that HT
- While it's **possible** that you've overlooked re-entering the PL tones on your Alinco, **and it's certainly worth double checking this**, I'm willing to be there's some kind of defect in the transmit stage...
- Get with a local ham and do some testing: use your 380 on the repeater to ask if someone can hear you on the input freq. If they can hear your 380 on the input freq, they should also be able to hear your Alinco on the input freq too. If they cannot... BOOM defect in your 70cm xmit stage (possibly including in the antenna, not just in the radio)
- If they CAN hear you on the input freq for BOTH rigs... then it's more likely that there **is** some kind of programming error on the Alinco
- Simplex testing with a friendly local may yield some info too

Love if you can come back and update your Q with results!

Good luck, rooting for you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have means to test output/to see if it is putting out any power? The PA for 440 may be damaged. You said you were "Picking up" stations. Does that imply you were not able to contact anyone? If so, try testing the output.

GL ES 73,
AI7OW